# 2 custom wp_query using the same rand with 'orderby' => 'rand'?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, custom-post-type

On my home page I'm showing 9 post, I have a load more button (with ajax) who calls 9 other posts and so on. Currently I'm ordering by 'date' but I would like to order by random. The problem is that my first wp_query orderby rand shows 9 random post, and when I load more post my second wp_query orderby random too can shows the same post from the first 9 post.

How can I randomize 2 wp_query with the same random ? Or is there another way to do this ?

---

As it is already suggest by a community member, I tried to store visibles Id in an array and used `post__not_in` like :

```
$query = new WP_QUERY(array(
        'post_type' => 'my_posts',
        'posts_per_page' => 9,
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'post__not_in' => $postNoIn,
        'paged' => $paged

    ));
```

But this didn't solve my problem.

The `$paged` variable is the current page number for my posts. I have 32 posts and I'm getting them 9 by 9, so there is 4 pages. When I use the second wp_query displays above, I get 9 random post minus the possible 9 first posts, so I can have less than 9 post and the query stopped when the last page in reached. I will have about 28 posts and not 32 cause the query stopped at page 4 and not until all posts are displayed.

Thanks in advance for your answers !

> **I've finally succeeded !**
>   **Here is my answer**

**I change my first query to get all post order by "rand", like :**

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'my_posts',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'rand'
    );
```

**Then in my loop I display the 9 first posts, after 9 posts I get the ID of all the others posts**

```
<?php
$index = 0;
$idsInt = array();

while ($the_query->have_posts()):
$the_query->the_post();

    if ($index < 9) : 

        get_template_part('part-template/content', get_post_format());
        $index++;

    else :

        array_push($idsInt, get_the_ID());

    endif; 

endwhile;
```

**After that I prepare my data to be use with ajax, for this I convert my list of `int` element into a `string` list**

```
$index = 0;
$idsString = array();

foreach ($idsInt as $id) {
    if ($index == 0) {
        $idsString .= " \"" . $id . "\"";
    } else {
        $idsString .= ", \"" . $id . "\"";
    }
    $index++;
}
```

**Here is my "Load More" button, I put in "data-id" my list of ID**

```
<div class="text-center">
    <a id="btn-load-more" data-id='[<?php echo $idsString ?>]' 
        class="home-load-more"
        data-page="1"
        data-url="<?php home_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" >
        <span class="text"><?php _e('Load More') ?></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**In my script.js, my ajax function looks like :**

```
$(document).on('click', '.home-load-more', function () {

    let that = $(this);
    let page = that.data('page');
    let newPage = page + 1;
    let ajaxurl = that.data('url');
    let ids = that.data('id');

    $.ajax({

        url: ajaxurl,
        type: 'post',
        data: {

            page: page,
            action: 'home_load_more',
            foo : ids

        },
        error: function (response) {

            console.log(response);

        },
        success: function (response) {

            if (!(response === "")) {

                that.data('page', newPage);
                $('.my_row').append(response);

            }
        }
    });
});
```

My `$_POST['page']` contains a number of page that increment on every Load More call, I'll explain why I'm using it later, and my `$_POST['foo']` contains my list of ID create in my first query loop.

**Now my php functions !**
**( explications of my code in the php comments ! )**

```
function home_load_more()
{

    $ids = ($_POST['foo']);
    $paged = $_POST["page"];
    $postIn = array();

    // I want to display only 9 posts on each calls
    for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {

        /* Here is my strange calcul to get ids 
         - from 0 to 8 on the first call
         - from 9 to 17 on the second call
         - from 18 to 26 on the third call
         and so on... 
         That is why I use the $paged, to get
         a value that is increment by one on every calls. */

        // Break if they are no more ids in the list
        if ($ids[($paged - 1) * 9 + $i] == null) {
            break;
        }

        // $postIn contains 9 posts IDs
        array_push($postIn, $ids[($paged - 1) * 9 + $i]);
    }

    $query = new WP_QUERY(array(
        'post_type' => 'my_posts',
        'orderby' => 'post__in',   // here I give my list of 9 ids
        'post__in' => $postIn
    ));

    if ($postIn[0] == null) {
        // Load More button won't display any posts
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
        if ($query->have_posts()) {

            while ($query->have_posts()) {
                $query->the_post();
                get_template_part('part-template/content', get_post_format());
            }
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    die();
}
```

That's it ! I think there is a best way to do this but I still want to show you my code. Hope this can help somebody, and if you have comment, questions, or ideas, don't hesitate to tell me in the comment section !

Answer (score 1):

Just store already visible ids somewhere in array, when requesting load more, send that array, then include it to `$args`

```
$args = array (
...
'post__not_in' => array( 1, 2, 3),
...
);
```

Comment: My wp_query are in 2 different files, how can I use a the variable with id globally ? I've already test this solution but I couldn't retrieve the ids in the second file, I used a global variable in my functions.php but always returning "null" in my second file.

Comment: You don't need to set this as global value, you can add id's as $_GET. and why you doing different files, when ou can do everything in `functions.php` creating separate functions on even one function.

Answer (score 0):

If you store a seed in a session, you can have the same order in page 2 oder 3, should be more easy than your solution.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31647/is-it-possible-to-paginate-posts-correctly-that-are-random-ordered

```
$args['posts_per_page'] = 10;
if (!isset($_SESSION['seed'])) {
    $_SESSION['seed'] = mt_rand();
}
$args['orderby'] = 'RAND(' . $_SESSION['seed'] . ')';
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

You are right, [Archit Gargi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18254155/archit-gargi), I added code

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34126538)